# configure: error: C preprocessor fails sanity check

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, configure, icc

I am compiling several libraries on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64. First I compiled the libraries with GCC 4.7.2 and it went all well. Then I tryed to recompile them with Inte Composer 2013 u2. Fot that purpose i did:

```
export CC=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icc
export CPP=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc
```

Then I run `./configure` and got the following error:

```
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc
configure: error: in `/var/www/workspace/freetype/freetype-2.4.11/builds/unix':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** [setup] Error 1
```

The config log file contains this error:

```
configure:3345: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:3415: result: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc
configure:3435: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc  conftest.c
conftest.c(14): error: identifier "Syntax" is undefined
             Syntax error
             ^

conftest.c(14): error: expected a ";"

compilation aborted for conftest.c (code 2)

configure:3435: $? = 2
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "FreeType"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "freetype"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.4.11"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "FreeType 2.4.11"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "freetype@nongnu.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:3435: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc  conftest.c
conftest.c(14): error: identifier "Syntax" is undefined
             Syntax error
             ^

conftest.c(14): error: expected a ";"

compilation aborted for conftest.c (code 2)
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Look into the `conftest.c` file to understand what is being tested.

Comment: Something that was supposed to write the `conftest.c` file (helpfully included in the log shown) did error out with "Syntax error", and the result doesn't compile. To find out what that is means exploring the twists and turns of autotools inards (*shudder*), maybe a leftover from a previous run. Try again, after making sure nothing of the previous builds remains (probably `make distclean` or something similar).

Comment: I tried to clean with `make clean` and `make distclean` but still the same problem. I downloaded another library and tried the same but it fails in the same way. Then I switched back to GCC and both libraries compiled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem may well be that the GNU make implicit variable that
denotes "your C++ compiler" is not `CPP` but `CXX`, whereas `CPP` is
the implicit variable that denotes "your C preprocessor"; so
your

```
export CPP=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc
```

tells `configure` that icpc is the preprocessor and leaves `CXX` presumably
defaulting to g++.

This is supported by the `./configure` error:

> checking how to run the C preprocessor... /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc

Try:

```
export CXX=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc
```

or just:

```
./configure CXX=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.2.146/bin/intel64/icpc
```

Comment: Good catch! (I overlooked it)

Comment: Sure, this solves the issue, but will force you to define the CPP variable every time you compile something. Why not explain how to compile GCC to look for CPP at the correct location in the first place?

Comment: Wow.  This fixed it for me, too.  So why does this wind up leading to "Syntax error" being inside the generated confdefs.h file?  Talk about a red herring...

Answer (score 10):

FWIW, I ran into this today and my solution was

`export CPP='<path to icpc> -E'`

that is, to tell configure that the preprocessor should be run with the `-E` flag.

Comment: This is many years later but THANK YOU. I would never have expected absolute path and -E flag to be necessary, but it was!!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Menno, in my case exporting didn't quite do it but it was close. Passing CPP=... to configure did the trick:

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc/ CC=/usr/local/gcc/bin/gcc \
 CXX=/usr/local/gcc/bin/g++ CPP='/usr/local/gcc/bin/g++ -E'
```